# Using quotation marks inside a SQL string

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to write the following a string to perform a SQL statement in Visual Basic:

```
 SELECT TOP 1 Questions.QuestionID, Questions.QuestionCategory & " : " & Questions.QuestionSubCategory AS Category FROM Questions WHERE (((Questions.QuestionDifficulty)=[?])) OR (((Questions.LastDateRevealed) Is Null)) OR ((Questions.LastDateRevealed)>=DateAdd("d",-7,Now())) ORDER BY Rnd(QuestionID);
```

However, when I try to either double quote to escape the quotation marks, I'm treated to erros about the string not being a valid and essentially breaks the code. How do I write this out?

The ultimate goal is that it would fit on a line like this:

```
Dim QuestionConnectionQuery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("", QuestionConnection)
```

With the SQL appearing within the quotes of the above line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to double the double quotes inside your SQL (that's how you escape double quotes in VB.NET).

Assuming the initial statement from your post is your working SQL:

`& " : " &` would become `& "" : "" &`,
and `DateAdd("d",-7,Now())` would become `DateAdd(""d"",-7,Now())`.

The full statement:

```
Dim QuestionConnectionQuery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Questions.QuestionID, Questions.QuestionCategory & "" :  "" & Questions.QuestionSubCategory AS Category FROM Questions WHERE (((Questions.QuestionDifficulty)=[?])) OR (((Questions.LastDateRevealed) Is Null)) OR ((Questions.LastDateRevealed)>=DateAdd(""d"",-7,Now())) ORDER BY Rnd(QuestionID);", QuestionConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL CONCAT here.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Questions.QuestionID, 
Questions.QuestionCategory + ' : ' + 
Questions.QuestionSubCategory AS Category 
FROM Questions 
WHERE (((Questions.QuestionDifficulty)=[?])) 
OR (((Questions.LastDateRevealed) Is Null)) 
OR ((Questions.LastDateRevealed)>=DateAdd("d",-7,Now())) 
ORDER BY Rnd(QuestionID);
```

even this also works fine

```
SELECT TOP 1 Questions.QuestionID,CONCAT(Questions.QuestionCategory ,':', Questions.QuestionSubCategory) AS Category 
FROM Questions 
WHERE (((Questions.QuestionDifficulty)=[?])) 
OR (((Questions.LastDateRevealed) Is Null)) 
OR ((Questions.LastDateRevealed)>=DateAdd("d",-7,Now())) 
ORDER BY Rnd(QuestionID);
```

Comment: I went ahead and added in the ultimate goal of this line of code. I can't use the multiple line version.

Comment: i don't get you, what is `multiple line version`

Comment: what database are you talking to?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: AccessDB